# Invoice mail not receiving after sending from back end without running cron job

Tags: magento2.2, email, invoice

Mail not getting triggered from back end in magento 2 after running cron job customer received the mail

Please help me to fix this. After send email from back end customer should receive the mail.

Comment: In Magento 2 transactional emails can be sent "asynchronously," or without the cron. Stores > Settings > Configuration > Sales > Sales Emails but all other emails are sent require cron to be run. you can setup a your cron jobs by following the instructions here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Answer (score 0):

Email will be sent immediately if asynchronous email sending is disabled in in global settings, Otherwise, email will be sent later during running of corresponding cron job.

Disable Asynchronous sending from

```
STORE > Configuration > Sales Emails > General Settings
```